# Delete Users in Spring Project (Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, web, jakarta-ee, spring-security

In my project, I added a function that removes students, now I want to be able to delete users. I wrote the code, but there is an error and it does not work. You can look at the controller and repositories, maybe on JSP page I made a mistake

Error -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.User adil.java.schoolmaven.repository.UserRepository.DeleteAccountById(java.lang.Long)! No property deleteAccountById found for type User!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:208)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:553)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:546)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property deleteAccountById found for type User!
```

AdminController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/allStudentsAdmin")
    public ModelAndView allStudentsForUser() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudentsAdmin");
        return mv;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/allStudentsAdmin");
        return mv;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("adminEditStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/editStudent")
    public String saveEditedUser(
    @RequestParam("id") Long id,
    @RequestParam("name") String name,
    @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
    @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            studentService.updateStudent(name, surname, file, studentService.getStudentById(id));
        } catch (FileSystemException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "redirect:/errors";
        }

        return "redirect:/admin/allStudentsAdmin";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/addStudentAdmin")
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudentAdmin");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addStudentAdmin")
    public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") @NonNull String name,
    @RequestParam("surname") @NonNull String surname,
    @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
    throws IOException {

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setSurname(surname);
        student.setName(name);

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            student.setAvatar(studentService.saveAvatarImage(file).getName());
        }
        studentService.saveStudent(student);
        return "redirect:/admin/allStudentsAdmin";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/addUser")
    public ModelAndView displayAddUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addUser");

        mv.addObject("user", new User());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addUser", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public String saveNewUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        userService.saveUser(user);
        return "redirect:/admin/allUsers";
    }

    @GetMapping("/allUsers")
    public ModelAndView allUsers(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("allUsers");
        List<User> users = userService.getAll();
        mv.addObject("users", users);
        return mv;
    }

    @GetMapping("/editUser/{id}")
    public ModelAndView editUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<User> user = userService.findUser(id);
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("editUser");
            mv.addObject("user", user.get());
            return mv;
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/allUsers");
    }

    @PostMapping("/editUser")
    public String saveEditedUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        userService.updateUser(user);
        return "redirect:/admin/allUsers";
    }


     @GetMapping(value = "/deleteUser/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteClientById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        userService.deleteAccountById(id);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/allUsers");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

UserService

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


public interface UserService {
    User saveUser(User user);
    List<User> getAll();

    Optional<User> findUser(Long id);

    User updateUser(User user);

    boolean deleteAccountById(Long id);

}
```

UserServiceImpl

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;


    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository repository) {
        super();
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAll() {
        return (List<User>) repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> findUser(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        return repository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteAccountById(Long id) {
        try {
            repository.deleteById(id);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public User updateUser(User user) {
        User targetUser = repository.findById(user.getId()).get();

        if (user.getLogin() != null) {
            targetUser.setLogin(user.getLogin());
        }

        if (user.getRole() != null) {
            targetUser.setRole(user.getRole());
        }

        if (user.getPassword() != null) {
            targetUser.setPassword(user.getPassword());

        }
        return repository.save(targetUser);


    }
}
```

AllUsers.JSP

```
<br>
    <br>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="f5f5f5" scope="col"># </font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="f5f5f5" scope="col">Login</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="f5f5f5" scope="col">Role</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="f5f5f5" scope="col">Edit</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="f5f5f5" scope="col">Delete</font></th>


        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="user" items="${users}" varStatus="loop">
            <tr>
                <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="f5f5f5" scope="row">${loop.index+1}</font></th>
                <td bgcolor="#000000"><font color="f5f5f5">${user.login}</font></td>
                <td bgcolor="#000000"><font color="f5f5f5">${user.role}</font></td>
                <td bgcolor="#000000">
                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/editUser/${user.id}">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                    </a>
                </td>

                <td bgcolor="#000000">
                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/deleteUser/${user.id}">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

StudentService.JAVA

```
public interface StudentService {

    List<Student> getAllStudents();

    Student getStudentById(Long id);

    boolean saveStudent(Student student);

    boolean deleteStudentById(Long id);

    File loadAvatarByFileName(String filename);

    File saveAvatarImage(MultipartFile avatarImage) throws IOException;

    Student updateStudent(String name, String surname, MultipartFile avatar, Student targetStudent) throws IOException;

}
```

Comment: Post your StudentService.java

Comment: Where is error thrown? Stack trace does not contain any line starting `adil.java...` that I would expect, so we do not know how it is related to posted code. Is any code using `studentService` relevant here, since you talk about (and error is related to) User/UserService/UserRepository?

Comment: Can you try renaming deleteAccountById to deleteUserById in UserService and UserServiceImpl?

Comment: I change but i have error adil.java.schoolmaven.repository.UserRepository.DeleteUserById(java.lang.Long)! No property deleteUserById found for type User!

Answer (score 0):

I just had remove it -

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByLogin(String username);
    User DeleteUserById(Long id); // Delete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using deleteById(Long id) method in UserRepository to delete the user